# Quoting a four-letter word

Tags: visual, letters

**What word is quoted in the middle of
  this 7- word line of 4-letter words?**

_ _ _ _                          
                        _ _ _ _                          
                        _ _ _ _                          
**‘ ‘_ _ _ _’ ’**  
                        _ _ _ _                          
                        L I K E                           T H I S **.**

The resultant sentence should make sense.

To help, here are all the words of that sentence,
in more than one way,
within 5 lines of letters.

```
    SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
      U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
      U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
      Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
      A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
```

To help more,   L I K E   and   T H I S  
came from shifting those 5 lines in different ways:

```
                                                         _______________
                                                        |               |
                   SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK|N   S F   S PPU|
             U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P  |H   P E  Y  L  |
     U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ|E   L EII   ART|
       Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI|L   I L  K  N  |
                 A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP|LEY S S   S EPF|
                          ______________________________|               |
                         |
     SEWEL E L S AKJ     |   L                           N   S F   S PPU
       U   P I H I       |   I    Each word is spelled   H   P E  Y  L
       U   EPD P PTL     |   K   downward somewhere in   E   L EII   ART
       Y   E D A   P     |   E   the next word's shift.  L   I L  K  N
       A   D H U IJL     |       ______________________  LEY S S   S EPF
                          \     /
    |               |      \   /
    |SEWEL E L S AKJ|TENPI R|L|FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
    |  U   P I H I  |  P   U|IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
    |  U   EPD P PTL|  E N S|KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
    |  Y   E D A   P|E     E|E|E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
    |  A   D H U IJL|NIO ERS|_|S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
    |_______________|
```

No unused letters have been added to the 5 shifty lines,
allowing for somewhat systematic considerations.

 
This is intended to be solved in a monospace text editor,
such as the answer editor at this site,
by shifting lines left and right
without altering their internal spacings.

 
All the better in an editor
where lines can be closer together, or even touch, vertically.
Here is a version of the lines where shapes are easier to recognize.

```
    @@@@@ @ @ @ @@@ @@@@@ @ @ @@@ @@@ @@@ @   @ @   @ @@@
      @   @ @ @ @     @   @ @@  @ @   @ @ @   @   @   @ @  @  @
      @   @@@ @ @@@   @ @ @ @@@   @   @ @ @ @ @@@ @@@ @@@ @   @ @@@   @@@
      @   @ @ @   @ @     @ @ @ @   @   @   @   @ @  @@ @   @ @  @  @
      @   @ @ @ @@@ @@@ @@@   @   @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @ @   @ @@@
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to directly answer it without building all the words? Its quite time taking I guess. :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that line of words reads:

> THIS LINE USES "THIS" JUST LIKE THIS

By shifting the lines, we can make the following words:

> FEEL ← (OPEN) PEEL (PENS)
>  JUST ← (EPEE) LINE (RUDE) (HEEL) THIS
>  LIKE ← JUST (HEED) (HELL) FEEL (ENDS) (REND)
>  LINE ← (RULE) (FILL) THIS PEEL
>  PEEL ← LINE (FEET) (HEEL) (FEEL)
>  THIS ← USES LIKE (FEES)
>  USES ← (ENDS) (REND) (THAT) PEEL (PEES) LINE
>
>  The words after the arrows appear vertically when forming a word and words in parentheses cannot be formed. (Words are often easy to discount by just looking at the top and bottom line. For example, HEEL cannot be formed, because there are no four consecutive 3-unit block on the last line.)
>
>  This "dependency graph" suggests the phrase above.

The shifts, backwards from the given LIKE THIS, where minuses mark the patterns and pluses mark the next word, are:

7.)

> THIS
>
> ```
>   ---------------         +
>   SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
>     U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
>     U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
>     Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
>     A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
>   ---------------         +
> ```

6.)

> LIKE
>
> ```
>                                 +                       ---------------
>                   SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
>             U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
>     U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
>       Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
>                 A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
>                                 +                       ---------------
> ```

5.)

> JUST
>
> ```
>                         ---------------                 +
>                   SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
>                     U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
>         U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
>   Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
>             A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
>                       -----------------                 +
> ```

4.)

> THIS
>
> ```
>   ---------------       +
>   SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
>     U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
>     U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
>     Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
>     A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
>   ---------------       +
> ```

3.)

> USES
>
> ```
>                                     ---------------         +
>               SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
>     U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
> U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
>                               Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
>         A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
>                                     ---------------         +
> ```

2.)

> LINE
>
> ```
>                                          ----------+----
>    SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
>                          U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
>              U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
>    Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
>  A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
>                                          ----------+----
> ```

1.)

> THIS
>
> ```
>   ---------------
>   SEWEL E L S AKJ TENPI R L FDD OET HYK N   S F   S PPU
>     U   P I H I     P   U IE  T E   E T T   P   H   P E  Y  L
>     U   EPD P PTL   E N S KTE   S   D L N H ESF EWF HSJ E   L EII   ART
>     Y   E D A   P E     E E E T   N   D   E   S L  FI L   I L  K  N
>     A   D H U IJL NIO ERS   S   SET TDI LFP LEY S S   S EPF
>   ---------------
> ```

Note that ...

> THIS is used three times. The dependencies seem to allow multiple uses with different predecessors. The THIS at the beginning doesn't need a predecessor of course.

And there are no unused letters:

> Marking all used letters in each step with the corresponding step number, we can see that all letters have been used:
>
> ```
>   77777 7 7 7 777 55555 3 3 333 333 333 6   6 6   6 666
>     7   7 7 7 7     5   2 22  2 2   3 3 3   3   6   6 6  6  6
>     7   777 7 777   5 5 5 555   5   2 2 3 3 333 333 333 6   6 666   666
>     7   7 7 7   7 3     5 5 5 5   5   5   2   2 2  22 6   6 6  6  6
>     7   7 7 7 777 555 555   5   333 333 333 666 6 6   6 666
> ```
>
> Many letters are used in several words, however. (In hindsight, it may have been useful to render used letters in lower-case in the step-by-step solution.)

Comment: You definitely have the hang of this. The puzzle statement now mentions that the resultant sentence should make sense, as was meant to be part of the puzzle all along, sorry that wasn't clear. And good for realizing that words might be re___, an integral part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I think 've got a better suggestion now.

Comment: Thanks! I liked the puzzle and I think the approach to use a monospace text editor as low-tech interface worked well.

Answer (score 1):

> THIS CODE WORD ENDS JUST LIKE THIS

Here it goes -

> [image]
>
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Hmmm. The answer is supposed to have seven words. And how can you make WORD when there isn't any O in the second line?

Comment: Updated. 7 words it is now. I didnt get your point for O

Comment: The word itself must occur in the pattern of the next word, just like LIKE appears in the pattern of THIS. There is a W on the first line, but no O on the second line, so ENDS can't come from WORD.